# Join multiple M4V to one file (maybe MKV?)

Tags: mkv, handbrake, avi

So I've recorded all my old Mini DV tapes to .AVI with dvgrab, then Deinterlaced them with Handbrake (Bob Method) on the High Profile but I'm left with a bunch of M4V files now (due to the 2 audio tracks).

I want to make one file out of each tape now and, if possible, also preserve the timestamps in the filename. I have no idea how to join them now tho since making an MKV out of them would result in the player acting up (VLC, MPC and WMP all bring different results when playing the MKV file for some reason).

What's the best way to get the deinterlaced M4V files into one file for each tape now? Or do you guys have some other methods for this while still deinterlacing the original footage from 50i to 50p?

Comment: Hi, what system would you be running? Mac, Windows, Linux?

Comment: Windows, if possible. If no other option is available than Linux or Mac I could use those too of course.

Comment: The answer below is in regards to Mac, Linux and Windows

Answer (score 5):

If you have [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) installed, see [this article](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) that basically says to create a file that has all of the names, or to use the following command

## Concat Protocol

```
ffmpeg -i 'concat:input1|input2' -codec copy output
```

Or

## Concat Video Filter

```
ffmpeg -i opening.mkv -i episode.mkv -i ending.mkv \
 -filter_complex '[0:0] [0:1] [1:0] [1:1] [2:0] [2:1] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]' \
-map '[v]' -map '[a]' output.mkv
```

Or

## Concat Demuxer

```
$ cat mylist.txt
file '/path/to/file1'
file '/path/to/file2'
file '/path/to/file3'

$ ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy output
```

### Which one to use

**concat protocol:** use with formats that support file level concatenation (MPEG-1, MPEG-2 PS, DV).

**concat filter:** use if you need to re-encode such as when applying filters.

**concat demuxer:** use when you want to avoid a re-encode and your format does not support file level concatenation.
If in doubt try the concat demuxer.

### When in Doubt, choose Demuxer

This article was originally published [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg)

Also, see http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-can-I-join-video-files_003f

Comment: how would I the concat demuxer to add the same outro video file to 100's of videos?

Comment: See [How to bulk add outro with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711013/how-to-bulk-add-outro-with-ffmpeg) and [ffmpeg concat video and audio out of sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35416110/ffmpeg-concat-video-and-audio-out-of-sync/35520705#35520705) Both of which can be integrated.